# Application crashes in Zxing's barcode scanner App on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I am developing an android application for a client.a tiny module from the application is the user can scan an barcode. When the scanning is performed successfully the details are fetched from the database.i  Integrate zxingbarcode scanner into MY Android app.Everything works fine..while the bar scanning process is performing if back button is pressed by the user the application crashes. some times  scanning takes time more for setup the device to focus correctly.the problem occurs when we exit without getting the result.

help please ..thanks in advance
the code is given below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button scanBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        //check for scan button
        if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
            //instantiate ZXing integration class
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            //start scanning
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult =      IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        //check we have a valid result
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //get content from Intent Result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            Log.d("scanContent", scanContent);

            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),CustomerDetailDisplay.class);
            i.putExtra("scanContent", scanContent);
            Log.d("scanContent", scanContent);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else{

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is your app that is crashing, not zxing. When you ask about a crash on SO, you really have to post the stack trace. In fact, it will already point you directly at the problem.

Comment: how can i check the scanning is completed or not..if not completed i want to do some actions so i can avoid the crash.thats the problem

Comment: Make sure that the `intent` is not null inside `onActivityResult`, before using it for `scanningResult `.